# How to replace object value based on hash table (ex. "State": "CO" changes to "State": "Colorado")

Tags: javascript, object, replace

**Simplified Version of Problem:**
I have an object that looks like this:

```
var info = [{
   "population": 1234,
   "state": "AL"
},{
   "population": 1234,
   "state": "AK"
}]
```

I need to replace the state two letter abbreviation with the actual state name. I have this available as follows:

```
var stateNames = {
  "AL": "Alabama",
  "AK": "Alaska"
};
```

The goal is to have it result in this:

```
[{
   "population": 1234,
   "state": "Alabama"
},{
   "population": 1234,
   "state": "Alaska"
}]
```

I have circled this long enough that I am pretty confused. My instructions to myself go like this:

1. Check every info.state value to see if it matches a key within stateNames.
2. If it matches, replace the info.state value with that stateNames value.
3. If there is no match, leave it.
4. Return object.

**Some Possibly Related Code:**

I have been searching SO for possible solutions and despite putting a good bit of time, don't have too much to offer. I do think using a foreach is probably right, and I think [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539236/how-to-replace-name-keys-in-a-javascript-keyvalue-map) is in the right direction:

```
Object.keys(hashmap).forEach(function(key) {
  var newkey = key + "xxx";
  hashmap[newkey] = hashmap[key];
  delete hashmap[key];
});
```

But I haven't been able to successfully adapt it. Any help or advice is very appreciated - thanks for reading!

**A JS Bin:**
http://jsbin.com/nojamoyeya/2/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve a state's full name by using its short name as the key in `stateNames`. Basically: `stateNames[shortName] = longName`. You can use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` to check if `stateNames` contains a specific key. Here is one way to do it:

```
var info = [{
   "population": 1234,
   "state": "AL"
},{
   "population": 1234,
   "state": "AK"
}];

var stateNames = {
  "AL": "Alabama",
  "AK": "Alaska"
};

info.forEach(function(state) {
  if(stateNames.hasOwnProperty(state.state)) {
    state.state = stateNames[state.state];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
info.forEach(function (item) {
    if (stateName[item.state]) {
        item.state = stateName[item.state];
    }
}
```

Would be one way.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var info = [{
    "population": 1234,
    "state": "AL"
}, {
        "population": 1234,
        "state": "AK"
    }];

var stateNames = {
    "AL": "Alabama",
    "AK": "Alaska"
};

info.forEach(function (inf) {
    if(inf.state in stateNames){
        inf.state = stateNames[inf.state];
    }
});

console.log(info);
```

Answer (score 1):

updated js bin is here 
http://jsbin.com/julexovete/1/edit?js,console

```
// Code
for(var i =0; i < info.length; i++){
  if(stateNames[info[i]["state"]]){
    info[i]["state"] = stateNames[info[i]["state"]];
  }

}
```